# How to add a character to a script line - piping $() or?

Tags: shell

When I do `echo $(ls)` I would like to add ";" to each line and a `"\n"`

Can this be done i a one-liner and what is it called when using `$()`. Is it piping?

Comment: First of, these are two quite different and separate questions. Second, it's not quite clear what your after in the first question. Do you want a `;` appended to each line? Do you want an additional line break or a literal `\n`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do

```
echo "$(ls | sed -e 's/$/;/g')"
```

The $() construction is called command substitution.

Note that enclosing the result in double quotes gives you the line breaks at the end of each entry.